# Solicitar login a una vista rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, devise

como hago para que al darle click al boton de new coment o new post de mi home#index, cuando me redirija a http://localhost:3000/post/new me solicite estar logeado. mientras que en el index puedo ver todos los post sin estar registrado

estoy usando devise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes usar [`before_action :authenticate_user!`](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers) en tu controlador (asumiendo que tu modelo de usuario es `user`). Ahí dependerá de lo que quieras implementar, pero lo común es que se agregue el filtro dentro de tu `ApplicationController`, ya que en general cualquier controlador debería loguear para poder ser usado y en los controladores donde no se vaya a usar, poner:

```
skip_before_action :authenticate_user!
```

Si para tu caso, quieres saltarte el estar logueado solo para el index de posts, debes usar:

```
skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: :index
```